# Swift Combine: merge multiple publishers and emit `true` when any of them emits `true`

Tags: swift, combine

I am trying to build a publisher that emits true when any of 5 other publisher emits true. I've managed to build a working version but it feels very icky, with the CombineLatest4 + CombineLatest and especially all the `$0.0 || $0.1 || $0.2 || $0.3` code.

I've tried Merge5, but that simply returns the value of the last value that was set it seems.

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

class Test {
  @Published var one = false
  @Published var two = false
  @Published var three = false
  @Published var four = false
  @Published var five = false
}

let test = Test()

var anyTrue = Publishers.CombineLatest4(test.$one, test.$two, test.$three, test.$four)
  .map { $0.0 || $0.1 || $0.2 || $0.3 }
  .combineLatest(test.$five)
  .map { $0.0 || $0.1 }

anyTrue.sink {
  print($0)
}

test.three = true
test.one = false
```

Is there a cleaner less repetitive way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have written this custom variadic `combineLatest` function that combines N publishers. Hopefully this is what you need:

```
func combineLatestN<P, T, E>(identity: T, reductionFunction: @escaping (T, T) -> T, publishers: P...) -> AnyPublisher<T, E> 
    where P: Publisher, P.Output == T, P.Failure == E {
    publishers.reduce(
        Publishers.Sequence<[T], E>(sequence: [identity]).eraseToAnyPublisher(), 
        { $0.combineLatest($1).map(reductionFunction).eraseToAnyPublisher() }
    )
}
```

The hard part was figuring out what the identity of the `reduce` should be. What publisher `x` satisfies `x.combineLatest(y).map(f) == y` for all `y`? One solution for `x` would be a publisher that publishes the identity of `f` once.

Usage:

```
let anyTrue = combineLatestN(
                identity: false, 
                reductionFunction: { $0 || $1 }, 
                publishers: test.$one, test.$two, test.$three, test.$four, test.$five)
```

Comment: I had to read it a few time to wrap my head around this code haha, but yea it seems work perfect for my use case!